# Proving a relation between chromatic number and existence of a cycle of certain length in a graph

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Prove that: If $G$ is a simple graph with $\chi(G)=k>2$, then there exists a cycle of length at least $k$.
I came across this problem from an online course notes on graph theory.

As the chromatic number of $G$ is $k$ there would be $k$ color classes (which are also independent sets) $G_{1},G_2,\ldots,G_k$ and that there would be at least one edge between $G_i,G_j$ for all $i \neq j$. From this argument, I could contruct a path of length $k$ but I'm not able to go ahead after this step.
Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: @bof Yes! I have assumed $k>2$. I forgot to mention